# How to solve this error "cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY"?

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I am entering this code for face detection:

```
import cv2
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('venv/Lib/site- 
packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('venv/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('Documents\Face detection\face1.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]

eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)

for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But when I run this code it gave this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nisha/Documents/Face detection/Face detection.py", line 9, in 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Please tell in detail how I get rid of this error or tell any changes or tell any alternative code which doesn't produce error and I can also complete my work. Actually, I am new in IT so I produce many error in small codes so please guide me so I can keep moving.

Comment: The `Mat` you are passing to `cvtColor` - `img`, is either empty or malformed. Check the path, it does not appear to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

The file you're trying to read is missing:

```
img = cv2.imread('Documents\Face detection\face1.jpg')
```

put `print( img.shape )` right after this line to make sure your image is read properly.

If you're working in Windows, I'd recommend you to `print('Documents\Face detection\face1.jpg')` as well and see what file you're trying to read. I bet you lose all path separators.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code to read image file:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()

img = cv2.imread(path+'Documents\Face detection\face1.jpg')
```